# Testing user access using role provider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have two projects inside my solution.

- UI.MVC4
- WebProviders

WebProviders are used in mvc4 to determine user permissions and memberships. This is working solution but I was thinkig to based on this learn how to test user access on certain administration pages.

Should I create MockRoleProvider and to use that role provider in my tests? I've read somewhere that I need to mock provider and inject it to the controller as part of controller context (HttpContextBase).

Can someone point me to the concrete example?